# Calculate $\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dydx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dydx$$
The only way I can think of doing this, is to do integration by parts. However, this will get messy very quickly. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Try the cov $x-y=u$, $x+y=v$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, this integral is not Lebesgue integrable, which means that almost the unique way to calculate it is to evaluate as it is. (Even we cannot interchange the order of integration without changing the value!) Indeed, if it were Lebesgue integrable then by interchanging the role of $x$ and $y$ we can conclude that the answer is $0$, which is simply not.

Comment: @sos440, OK. Is the iterated integral and isn't the integral on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. And the iterated integrals are different. Very interesting and esay counterexample.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, Yes. More precisely, what I mean is that $$ \iint_{[0,1]^{2}} \left| \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^{3}} \right| \, dxdy = +\infty $$ as double integral. Consequently, the given iterated integral behaves like a conditionally convergent series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write 
$$\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} = \frac{2x}{(x + y)^3} - \frac{1}{(x + y)^2}$$
Integrating this with respect to $y$ from $0$ to $1$ gives
$$-\frac{x}{(x + y)^2}\bigg|_{y=0}^{y=1} + {1 \over x + y}\bigg|_{y=0}^{y=1}$$
$$= -{x \over (x + 1)^2} + {1 \over x} + {1 \over x + 1} - {1 \over x}$$
$$={1 \over (x + 1)^2}$$
Integrating this with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $1$ gives ${1 \over 2}$.